# Does China have "parasitism" law prohibiting people from not working?

Tags: employment, labor-law, china

I did a lot of research answering this Politics.SE question: "[Is China really Communist?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25743/is-china-really-communist/25744#25744)".

I was able to answer most items I decided to research (some of the answers were less intuitive than expected), but one item eluded me, and it's a legal one.

One of Marx's 10 tenets of establishing Communism, was "Equal liability of all to work". In USSR, [there was a formal law based on the idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitism_(social_offense)#Soviet_Union), prohibiting "social parasitism".

However, I was unable to find any mention of such law in PRC - but not being a lawyer OR speaking any Chinese, it's possible I simply didn't know the right terms to search for. Hence, the question for Law.SE:

## Does People's Republic of China have "parasitism" law prohibiting people from not working or punishing them for not having a job?

Comment: Good question. Not sure how to answer it myself, however, in part, because not all legal obligations in China are codified in a nice neat statutory compilation, so it might not be obvious that a law had that effect, even if it did.

Answer (score 2):

**Does [the] People's Republic of China have "parasitism" law prohibiting people from not working or punishing them for not having a job?**

I cannot find any such requirement in either the [Criminal Law](http://www.asianlii.org/cn/legis/cen/laws/cl104/#2) or the [Labour Law](http://www.asianlii.org/cn/legis/cen/laws/llotproc353/), but I see that the latter makes two references to providing state benefits to the "*unemployed*":

> Article 70
>
> The State shall develop social insurance undertakings, establish a social insurance system, and set up social insurance funds so that laborers may receive assistance and compensations under such circumstances as old age, illness, work-related injury, unemployment and child-bearing.

And:

> Article 73
>
> Laborers shall, in accordance with the law, enjoy social insurance benefits under the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> - (4) unemployment ...
>
> ...

The Labour Law also includes this, which coupled with the provision of state benefits for the unemployed, seems to suggest that the PRC do not prohibit "social parasitism" (officially anyway):

> Article 5
>
> The State shall take various measures to promote employment...

Comment: Typically "unemployment" is when you want to work but can't find a job, whereas I'd think "parasitism" would be when you could be working but choose not to.